# Read pixel colors in android

Tags: android, localization

I have an image of a person taken from camera in android phone. I want to perform face localization in this image using the concept of color segmentation. For this I need to read the value of Red, Green and Blue componets of  pixel in android. Please tell me how to do this in android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `public int getPixel (int x, int y)` method, it returns Color of specific location(pixel)

Please visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: You should add a bit of description when posting a link.